# Getting error while making new angular app

Tags: angular-cli

I ran **ng new my-app** command on terminal and I am getting this error

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...d//PMMK34X5bQG9jcknko'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/io/.npm/_logs/2018-09-30T04_36_48_556Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.

Comment: Clear your npm cache and try again

Answer (score 1):

Clear your `npm` **cache** and try again.

If not work then **update** `npm` and `angular-cli`, that will work.